# Java API for Wiimote (Wii Remote) on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, wiimote, java

I'm looking for a reliable Java API for a Wiimote (Wii Remote). I also need it to run on Windows XP.

Does anybody here know of one?

Comment: Google "wiimote java api" = http://code.google.com/p/jwiimote/

Answer (score 3):

Here is one that I found: [motej](http://motej.sourceforge.net/). It says "motej" is "a Wiimote Library for Java." I have not looked at it much but it looks like it could help you out.

Good luck.